# Как передать массив в процедуру?

Tags: ассемблер

Недавно начал изучать ассемблер и это моя первая программа на нем. Задумка такова: при нажатии кнопки(строка 148 и далее) должен происходить вызов процедуры InptProc, внутри которой и будет происходить взаимодействие с массивом(его заполнение основываясь на параметрическом джампе). Проблема в том, что никак не могу передать массив в процедуру: пытался через lea, пытался через стэк - ничего не выходит. Каким образом передать BoardArray в InptProc?

```
.386 
.MODEL flat, stdcall 
.STACK 2048
OPTION CaseMap:None
 
INCLUDE D:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
WinMain PROTO :DWORD,:DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD
 
.DATA 
    AppName db "Tic-Tac-Toe game", 0
    ClassName db "GUIClass", 0
    ButtonClass db "button", 0
    ButtonText db " ", 0
    PCmmnText db "Congratulations!", 0
    POneWinText db "Player 1 WIN!", 0
    PTwoWinText db "Player 2 WIN!", 0
    Draw db "Draw", 0
    BoardArray db 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 
.DATA?
    hInstance HINSTANCE ?
    CommandLine LPSTR ?
    hwndButton HWND ?
 
.CONST
    ButtonIDLT equ 0
    ButtonIDMT equ 1
    ButtonIDRT equ 2
    ButtonIDLM equ 3
    ButtonIDMM equ 4
    ButtonIDRM equ 5
    ButtonIDLB equ 6
    ButtonIDMB equ 7
    ButtonIDRB equ 8
 
.CODE 
start:
    mov ebx, offset BoardArray
    mov ecx, 0
    invoke GetModuleHandle, 0
    mov hInstance, eax
    invoke GetCommandLine
    mov CommandLine, eax
    invoke WinMain, hInstance, 0, CommandLine, SW_SHOWDEFAULT
    invoke ExitProcess, eax
    WinMain PROC hInst:HINSTANCE, hPrevInst:HINSTANCE, CmdLine:LPSTR, CmdShow:DWORD
    local wc:WNDCLASSEX
    local hwnd:HWND
    local msg:MSG
 
    mov wc.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
    mov wc.style, CS_HREDRAW OR CS_VREDRAW
    mov wc.lpfnWndProc, offset WndProc
    mov wc.hbrBackground, COLOR_BTNFACE+1
    push hInst
    pop wc.hInstance
    mov wc.lpszMenuName, 0
    mov wc.lpszClassName, offset ClassName
    invoke LoadIcon, 0, IDI_APPLICATION
    mov wc.hIcon, eax
    mov wc.hIconSm, eax
    invoke LoadCursor, 0, IDC_ARROW
    mov wc.hCursor, eax
    invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc
    invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, \
    addr ClassName,\
    addr AppName,\
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW AND NOT WS_MAXIMIZEBOX AND NOT WS_SIZEBOX,\
    CW_USEDEFAULT,\
    CW_USEDEFAULT,\
    210,\
    340,\
    0,\
    0,\
    hInst,\
    0
 
    mov hwnd, eax
 
    invoke ShowWindow, hwnd, CmdShow
    invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd
 
    .WHILE 1
        invoke GetMessage, addr msg, 0, 0, 0
    .BREAK .IF (!eax)
        invoke TranslateMessage, addr msg
        invoke DispatchMessage, addr msg
    .ENDW
 
    mov eax, msg.wParam
 
    RET
WinMain ENDP
WndProc PROC hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage, 0
 
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CREATE
 
        ; 0:0 - first cell top
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        10, 10, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDLT, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 0:1 - second cell top
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        70, 10, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDMT, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 0:2 - third cell top
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        130, 10, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDRT, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 1:0 - first cell middle
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        10, 70, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDLM, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 1:1 - second cell middle
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        70, 70, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDMM, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 1:2 - third cell middle
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        130, 70, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDRM, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 2:0 - first cell bottom
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        10, 130, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDLB, hInstance, 0
 
        ; 2:1 - second cell bottom
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        70, 130, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDMB, hInstance, 0
        mov cx, 1
 
        ; 2:2 - third cell bottom
        invoke CreateWindowEx, 0, addr ButtonClass, addr ButtonText, \
        WS_CHILD OR WS_VISIBLE OR BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,\
        130, 130, 55, 55, hWnd, ButtonIDRB, hInstance, 0
 
    .ELSEIF uMsg == WM_COMMAND ; НАЖАТИЕ КНОПКИ
        mov eax, wParam
        .IF eax == ButtonIDLT
            push ButtonIDLT
            call InptProc
             
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDMT
            push ButtonIDMT
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDRT
            push ButtonIDRT
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDLM
            push ButtonIDLM
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDMM
            push ButtonIDMM
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDRM
            push ButtonIDRM
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDLB
            push ButtonIDLB
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDMB
            push ButtonIDMB
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ELSEIF eax == ButtonIDRB
            push ButtonIDRB
            INC ecx
            call InptProc
        .ENDIF
    .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
        RET
    .ENDIF
 
    xor eax, eax
    RET
WndProc ENDP
 
InptProc PROC
    mov ebx, esp ; get button id
    ; mov esi, псевдо-получение массива
    TEST ebx, 1
    ; псевдо-прыг если 1
    ; mov [esi], ecx
    RET
InptProc ENDP
END start
```

Пытался передать массив следующим образом:

```
.CODE
start:
   mov edx, offset BoardArray ; указатель на массив в edx

; тело процедуры WndProc
; тело "нажатия кнопки"
   push edx ; пушим edx с указателем на массив в стэк
; тело процедуры InptProc
   mov esi, esp ; достаю указатель на массив из стэка
   mov eax, 1000
   mov [esi], eax ; на этой стадии программа крашится
```

**UPD:**
Я опробовал советы от Marzik7512. Почему-то программа все еще крашится. На всю прогу у меня один пуш в стэк: push hInst с последующим pop cw.hInst. Пытался пушить esi (хранит offset BoardArray) перед push hInst. Доставать пытался уже после ухода hInst из стэка - программа все так же крашится на стадии работы с массивом:

```
; тело процедуры
mov edx, 10
pop esi
mov [esi], edx ; - краш
```

Comment: А что мешает процедуру `InptProc` сделать по-нормальному:`InptProc PROC btnId:DWORD, ptrToArray:DWORD .... InptProc ENDP`? Или по заданию нужно всё через `[esp]`?

Comment: @LShadow77 все дело в том, что у меня нет никакого задания. Просто я пытаюсь сделать свое первое приложение. По какой-то из причин даже совет mazik7512 с push/pop у меня не работает: во время обращения к массиву через: mov [esi], edx (в edx хранится число 10. Выполняю mov edx, 10 в теле процедуры) у меня происходит краш программы

Comment: @Lovona краш происходит скорее всего, потому что в `esi` лежит что-то не то. Попробуйте пройтись дебаггером и посмотреть нужное ли значение в регистре.

Comment: @Lovona наиболее частая причина крэша - попытка обращения по некорректному адресу. Ещё может быть разрушение фрейма процедуры в стеке из-за путаницы с push/pop. Не забывайте, что сразу, после вызова процедуры с помощью call, по адресу [esp] хранится адрес возврата, а уже за ним - переданные параметры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mov esi, esp ; достаю указатель на массив из стэка

Вы здесь достаете не указатель на массив, а **адрес** верхушки стэка **(не её содержимое)**. Тогда уже нужно `mov esi, [esp]`.

**Примечание**. Обычно значения из стэка достают с помощью `pop` (в вашем случае `pop esi`). Но будьте аккуратны `pop` убирает значение из стэка.